# PHP remove single-quote in (utf-8?) string

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I want to load strings from a utf-8 mysql tables and compare them to strings which I load from a .csv file in PHP. I have (I assume) an encoding problem and struggle to compare identical strings with a single quote in them. The single quote seems to be different between the strings I loaded from the DB and the one from the .csv file.

for instance: `Hello'World` has following `bin2hex` dump between .csv and the string loaded from a mysql-table

mysql: `68656c6c6f[26233033393b]776f726c64`

csv:   `68656c6c6f776f726c64`

It would be fine to just remove the single quote from the mysql string but all attempts to `regex` it away or do `str_replace` failed. Also running explicit `utf8_encode/utf8_decode` didn't help to get a string that evaluates positive for an equality check but I don't get this string cleaned.

does someone has an idea how to handle the single quote? It would be possible to rebuild the database table in a different encoding (currently its UTF-8) if this would be easier?

Comment: It is possible you can use filter_var as in: $newstring = filter_var($oldstring, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH); It really depends on the current character set and the actual codes used in the original strings.

Comment: In the MySql hexdump, `26233033393b` corresponds to HTML entity for an apostrophe `&#039;` However, I can't comprehend the `[]` square brackets there… and why the csv hexdump does not contain apostrophe code (`27`) at all:)

Comment: I added the [] for highlighting the difference between the two hex dumps but thank you for the hint with the apostrophe! This helps me already. Thanks!